# Pthreads in C. Simple example doesn't work

Tags: c, pthreads, dev-c++

I'm starting programming using Pthreads. I use Dev-C++ and I linked library to the project. Simple program compiles, but it doesn't work. Below I attached the code. Does anyone know what's the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <windows.h>


void *func (void* x){
    printf("(%s)",'Hi. It's thread number 1');
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    int x=1;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, &x);
    pthread_join(thread,1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Define: ***Doesn't work***

Comment: Take a look at that `printf` call again.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What is your expected behavior? Also, don't use `Dev-C++`, it's incredibly outdated. Finally, unless you have explicitly downloaded the pthread library for Windows, Windows does not natively support posix threads.

Comment: What do you mean when you write, "It doesn't work" ? What did the program do, and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: Download a pthread library* (mingw-w64 provides winpthreads in SVN trunk)

Comment: The `printf` line cannot compile for various reasons. Please show your *real code*.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
printf("(%s)",'Hi. It's thread number 1');
```

should be

```
printf("(%s)", "Hi. It's thread number 1");
```

String literals are enclosed using quotation marks `"`.

---

Also passing `1` to [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) as 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter most likley invokes undefined behaviour, as it tells the function to write a value of type `void *` to address `1`, which is not expected to be pointing to valid memory.

Comment: OP claims that his program actually compiles, so I am afraid that this is a copy/paste "error". But who knows, we'll see ... - Good point about `pthread_join()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Problem solved. The problem was with the argument of pthread_join and quotes in printf.

Comment: @Pawel: You are welcome. If this answered your question, you may mark it as such, by clicking the answer's check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

Did the compiler not complain about that huge multi-character character constant?  (It should have complained twice; once about a huge multi-character character constant, and once for passing a character constant to printf when printf is expecting a string.)  Try double quotes around your string on line 8 instead.